# append list in class by python

Tags: python, list, class

Imagine that I have a list of countries, and for each country I want to store some info ( animal, fruit, river) of it. But the number of animals, fruit and rivers is unknown, it is input from user. Therefore, I want to use list in class as below but don't know how to append the list.

```
class data():
    def __init__(self, animal, fruit, river):
        self.animal = []
        self.fruit = []
        self.river = []
    def update_info(self, animal, fruit, river):
        self.animal.append(animal)
        self.fruit.append(fruit)
        self.river.append(river)

country = []
for i in ["Japan", "Australia", "India"]:
    country.append(i)
country[0] = data.update_info("Monkey", "persimmon", "Shinano")
country[1] = data.update_info("Kangaroo", "apple", "Murray")
country[2] = data.update_info("Tiger", "mango", "Ganges")
```

Comment: your for loop is creating a list of strings. I think you want to make a list of objects of class data. Then you should add an attribute to the data class that is country.

Comment: Your `.update_info()` method *doesn't return anything*.  Assigning the result anywhere is therefore pointless.

Comment: sorry for the unclear problem. i want to use country list to retrieve info of each country later. info of each country is stored in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of objects of class data. You can also use list comprehension when generating the objects

```
class data():

def __init__(self, country):
    self.country=country
    self.animal=[]
    self.fruit=[]
    self.river=[]

def update_info(self,animal,fruit,river):
    self.animal.append(animal)
    self.fruit.append(fruit)
    self.river.append(river)

country=[data(i) for i in ["Japan","australia","India"]]

country[0].update_info("Monkey","persimmon","Shinano")
country[1].update_info("kangooru","apple","Murray")
country[2].update_info("tiger","mango","Ganges")
```

Comment: Thank you, i don't think it is easy like this before you did.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like each country has one of each attribute, but you have a variable number of countries.

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't need a list inside the class:

```
class data():
    def __init__(self, animal, fruit, river):
        self.animal = animal
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.river = river
```

You would then create the list of countries like

```
countries = [
    data("Monkey", "Persimmon", "Shinano"),
    data("Kangaroo", "Apple", "Murray"),
    data("Tiger", "Mango", "Ganges")
]
```

You aren't associating a name with the country by doing this, so it may be better to use a dictionary rather than a list:

```
countries = {
    'Japan': data("Monkey", "Persimmon", "Shinano"),
    'Australia': data("Kangaroo", "Apple", "Murray"),
    'India': data("Tiger", "Mango", "Ganges")
}
```

To append to the list, do

```
countries.append(data('some_animal', 'some_fruit', 'some_river'))
```

To insert into the dictionary:

```
countries['some_country'] = data('some_animal', 'some_fruit', 'some_river')
```

Comment: the problem is the number of country and the country attributes are unknown, because they will be collected by user or from a file. that's why a want to use a list to store country while a class to store its attribute

Comment: @HoangMinhNguyen. You can initialize a new instance of `data` and append it to `countries`.